# Executing Powershell Script Remotely - MSAccess not launching

Tags: c#, powershell, ms-access

I am trying to execute a Powershell script remotely that will launch an accdb file via MSAccess. I am able to get the Powershell script to execute successfully, but MSAccess is not launching since I know that the test.accdb file that I have is not getting updated. What am I missing in my code in order to be able to launch MSAccess? Or is it not possible?

My code is running in a Windows 2012 R2 environment in IIS and is being executed by a service account that has Admin privileges to the machine. If I run the code logged in as that service account, it works fine without issues. If I execute it remotely, only part of the code is executed

My code for the .NET app is as follows (running under service account). I've changed some of the private information, but it doesn't effect the code.

```
    internal static HttpStatusCode ExecuteRemoteCommand()
    {
        WSManConnectionInfo connectioninfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
        connectioninfo.ComputerName = "testcomputer";
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                var re = ps.AddScript(@"\\testcomputer\test\StartTest.ps1");
                var results = re.Invoke();
            }
        }

        return HttpStatusCode.Created;
    }
```

My Powershell code is as follows:

```
try {

    $msAccess = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\msaccess.exe"
    $fileLocation =  "C:\test\DBT.accdb"
    Start-Process -FilePath $msAccess -ArgumentList $fileLocation -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden -WorkingDirectory "C:\test" 
    $today = Get-Date
    "SUCCESS: " + $today > "c:\test\TestExecutionSuccess.txt"

}
Catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message > "c:\test\TestExecutionError.txt"
}
```

**In both cases**, the one where I run the script locally and the one where I execute it remotely, **the TestExecutionSuccess.txt file is created.**

**However, in ONLY the local test run is the DBT.accdb file updated.**

Comment: What user does the C# app run under? Is it running under IIS?

Comment: Yes, it is running under IIS under a service account. The service account, company\testremote also has admin privileges on the testcomputer server and is an Active Directory account

Comment: So the issue is because it doesnt have a screen to load up to. 

On ur local machine it works because the User the code is running on is yourself and you are logged in and have Interactive rights. When your logged into the Service user then that user has Interactive rights and the excel loads.  On the remote machine not logged in as service account its running under a service user and can write to files but it doesnt have Interactive rights and thus cant load the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

So lets talk about the problems

1 : You can run the code and open Excel when you run the code under your User account logged in.

2 : You can run the code and open Excel when you run the code under your the service account logged in.

3 : you can you the code But Excel will not load if you are not logged into the user.

Why?

This is about Interactive flag. When you are logged into a user then you have can load up GUI's using COM. If you are not logged into a user then you can not load a GUI.

Here is a more indeepth explanation from
[Microsoft Interactive User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/interactive-user)

Answer (score 0):

With ArcSet's guidance, I think I was able to figure out what the issue was. His answer led me down the path of investigating which version of powershell was running. Turned out the C# code was running Powershell x64 instead of x86 (32-bit) version. The office installation is 32-bit and hence why I couldn't run MSAccess.

I couldn't figure out how to run x86 version of Powershell from the C# code, but what I did was put the launch of MSAccess into a batch file and then executed the batch file from my powershell code. Not super clean, but it worked. Access is now running properly.

Here is the batch file code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14"
MSACCESS.EXE C:\test\DBT.accdb
```

and the new version of the PowerShell script:

```
try {

    $msAccess = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\msaccess.exe"
    $fileLocation =  "C:\test\executeTest.bat"  
    cmd.exe /c $fileLocation
    $today = Get-Date
    "SUCCESS: " + $today > "c:\test\TestExecutionSuccess.txt"

}
Catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message > "c:\test\TestExecutionError.txt"
}
```